# Cannot start apache after reboot on dedicated server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have some websites running on a dedicated server. One of them it's written in CodeIgniter by me and has wordpress integrated. Tonight, this sequence of events happened:

1. Due to my mistake, wordpress automatically updated and reintroduced a bug i (badly) fixed 2 months ago by editing the core. Due to this bug, pages take years to load (because one of the database tables is huge)
2. Therefore i tried some debugging to re-fix it. During debugging i opened many times one of these pages, to test the fixes. Suddenly i couldn't open any of the websites, therefore i thought the server crashed, and i assumed it was due to the overload carried by this bug (CPU running at 100% for most of the time).
3. I hard rebooted the server. A reboot 99% of times solves a lot of problems and i thought it was a good solution...

After reboot i realized i cannot start Apache anymore. I tried logging in via SSH (which works), but once i try to start apache by using `apachectl -k graceful` i get the following error:

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/racebook/sd/download/www] does not exist
httpd not running, trying to start
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

I hour since reboot and nothing happened...Can you help me fixing this?

Additional info:

- Server Provider: [Kimsufi](http://www.kimsufi.com/us/en/)
- OS info: Linux ns362512.ip-91-121-174.eu 3.14.27-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 14:02:42 CET 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- IP: 91.121.174.40
- Webmin login: [ns362512.ip-91-121-174.eu:10000](http://ns362512.ip-91-121-174.eu:10000)

Comment: Does that directory actually still exist?

Comment: What does your configuration virtual hosts configuration look like?

Comment: Can you also  check that apache has permission to access that directory?

Comment: Ok, i just realized i previously deleted that directory on FTP few weeks ago. I Manually created it again using SSH, but now i got the same exact message EXCEPT i don't get the warning anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on that output I think it's not starting because it's already running.  You can try `apachectl restart` to see if that works instead, but if it doesn't, try killing all Apache processes with `killall httpd` or `killall -9 httpd`.  Then start it with `apachectl start`.

If it still doesn't start (or even if it does but you want to figure out what was happening), you can check the master apache error log to see if there's anything useful in there.

If your site lives in /home/racebook/sd/download/www (not sure if that's your site or some other directory that you don't care about) and you're getting that warning message that that directory doesn't exist, that should be what you look into next.

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy... :O 
Thanks, now i can take my Computer Science Degree and flush into the toliet!! ahahah Thanks man, that fixed everything! restart didn't work, killall + start worked,instead